# WASD movement within a Flash SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So, I was going to make a large room inside of my CPPS, however, I find the need for multiple rooms linked together with a little annoying. I was wondering if I could increase the size of my rooms that were linked together and scroll around it using WASD.

This is the environment that I am trying to manage:

This is a part of an island I was going to develop, it's a rough picture but you get the idea that it would continue to the left. That's where I want it to scroll.

[image]

Am I a crazy to try and do this? Is this even possible? Any comments will help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you're looking for is a masked container.

1. Place your map in a container.
2. Set the X & Y coordinate by an event that interests you (character
   reaches edge of map, clicking on a button, etc...)
3. The layers on top (in this case your UI) sit above your container. 
   If you had other items that don't cover your worldmap, you'd add a
   mask to the container by setting `myContainer.mask = myShape`

For fun, I went ahead and wrote an example which you can run in a clean project.  This should demonstrate the map panning concept.  Try your WASD keys, or simply move the mouse.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

// Our container for the map.
var container:Sprite;
// For the sake of smoothly animating to its destination, track the X & Y coordinates.
var destX:Number = 0;
var destY:Number = 0;

init();
function init():void {
    // Create a backdrop (mostly for mouseMove)
    var bg:Sprite = new Sprite();
    bg.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
    bg.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x00);
    bg.graphics.drawRect(100, 100, stage.stageWidth - 200, stage.stageHeight - 200);
    bg.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(bg);

    // Our container "map"
    container = new Sprite();
    addChild(container);

    // Create a mask
    var m:Shape = new Shape();
    m.graphics.beginFill(0x00);
    m.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth - 200, stage.stageHeight - 200);
    m.graphics.endFill();
    m.x = m.y = 100;
    container.mask = m;

    // Event Listeners
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyboardMovement);
    addEventListener("mouseMove", cursorMovement);
    addEventListener("enterFrame", updateMap);

    // Populate the map with shapes
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var c:Shape = createCircle();
        container.addChild(c);
        c.x = random(0, stage.stageWidth * 2); // Random X Coordinate
        c.y = random(0, stage.stageHeight * 2); // Random Y Coordinate
    }
}

function createCircle():Shape {
    // Creates a randomly sized/colored circle
    var c:Shape = new Shape();
    c.graphics.beginFill(random(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)); // Random Color
    c.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,random(4,20)); // Random Size
    c.graphics.endFill();
    return c;
}

function keyboardMovement(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    var speed:int = 100
    switch (e.charCode) {
        case 115: // s:down
            speed = -speed;
        case 119: // w:up
            destY = clamp(destY + speed, -this.loaderInfo.height, 0);
            break;
        case 100: // d:right
            speed = -speed;
        case 97: // a:left
            destX = clamp(destX + speed, -this.loaderInfo.width, 0);
            break;
    }
}

function cursorMovement(e:Event):void {
    destX = -mouseX;
    destY = -mouseY;
}

function updateMap(e:Event):void {
    container.x += (destX - container.x) * 0.1;
    container.y += (destY - container.y) * 0.1;
}

function random(low:Number, high:Number):Number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
}

function clamp(original:Number, low:Number, high:Number):Number {
    return (original > high) ? high : (original < low) ? low : original;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I would have ever thought about using a mask until now! Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work in AS2? I tried moving to AS3 but quickly realised that _global no longer exists and means that I will have to change every swf using that feature. I am going to move my files over to AS3 eventually, however, for the time being, is there a way for this to run in AS2? Thanks again!

Comment: If there is a way to do it in AS2, it is outside my knowledge.  Just about anything you do in AS2 has an analogue in AS3, but the reverse is not true due to the more robust nature of AS3.

However, if all you're doing is using _global to store variables, you can create your own (either in your own document code, or in a static class).  For example:  

`var _global:Object = {};`
`_global.myVar = "Hello World!";`
`trace(_global.myVar);`

Comment: Tried adding in 'var _global:Object = {};' but it still wouldn't load the necessary files to make the room playable. I assume that the code used in the load.swf is AS2 and I would have to change the code inside that as well but while I was looking inside that file I could not find _global.getCurrentEngine. Thanks for the help though.